# Minitest hanging on stylesheet_link_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, simplecov

An error in Minitest is generated for four actions (index, show, new, edit)

```
ActionView::Template::Error: Error: @supports condition expected declaration
    on line 9749:12 of stdin
>> @supports (scroll-snap-type) {
-----------^
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9
```

The line of the application layout invokes

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

The controller test suite has 13 runs. 9 pass, but they all deal with non-view methods (update, create, destroy).

Under no circumstance of having `stylesheet_link_tag` active, plus or minus its options, does the test pass.  The moment it is set to `<%#` the test runs (and passes)

The oddity is that these tests passed in the past and the `application.html.erb` was not modified.  Turbolinks cannot be removed (and would seem odd to have a test suite fail for that).

The only change has been the introduction of coverage and rubycritic gems. Yet calling the tests in two different ways

```
rails test test/controllers/channels_controller_test.rb
COVERAGE=TRUE rails test test/controllers/channels_controller_test.rb
```

leads to the same result.
The test helper gets the first two lines toggled as well to test without coverage

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails'

# Previous content of test helper now starts here

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative "../config/environment"
require "rails/test_help"
require 'webmock/minitest'


class ActiveSupport::TestCase

  fixtures :all

  def log_in_as(user, shop)
    post user_session_url, params: { user_id: user.id, active_shop_id: @site.shop_id }
  end

end
```

Removing the gems

```
# gem 'rubycritic', '~> 4.6', '>= 4.6.1', require: false

group :test do
#  gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.21.2'
end
```

also generates the same result.

What should be configured so that minitest knows how to handle turbolinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to resolving this was in a component of the error message

```
 on line 9749:12
```

then it could only have come from a css file. examining the resulting `application.css` file allowed to go to that line immediately.